# Is it possible to convert locale string to decimal number with thousand separators in JS?

Tags: javascript, parsing, locale

I'm trying to find a way to convert a string which has been outputted by Number.toLocaleString() to a float with thousand and decimal separators. The problem is that I can't find a way to do it for any locale : Chinese numbers have a separator every 4 digits, India starts with 3 then every 2 digits, German separators are exactly the opposite of English ones, French have spaces for thousands etc...

This is basically what I want :

```
Indian : '10,00,00,123' => '100000.123'
French : '123 456,789' => '123456.789'
```

Is there a library that can do this ? I do have the locale before parsing with

> navigator.language

if it helps

Thanks in advance

UPDATE : This is what I came up with and it works great for Arabic Numerals :

```
let localeString = '123,45,67,89.57982';

console.log(reformat(localeString));

function reformat(str) {
    let rawNumber;
    let decimalIndex;
    let charToRemove = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(str[i])) {
            //concatenating numbers
            rawNumber = parseInt(`${rawNumber ? rawNumber : ''}${str[i]}`);
        } else {
            decimalIndex = i;
            charToRemove++;
        }
    }

    return format(rawNumber, decimalIndex, charToRemove);
}

function format(number, decimalIndex, charToRemove) {
    if (decimalIndex) {
        // Adding decimal to the right place
        return number / Math.pow(10, number.toString().length - decimalIndex + charToRemove - 1);
    } else {
        return number;
    }
}
```

EDIT : it doesn't work as intended as there's no way to know if a separator is a decimal one or a thousand (no way to differentiate int numbers with thousand separators vs decimal number)

Comment: `toLocaleString()` can take arguments to specify which locale to use ie. `toLocaleString('de-AT', { currency: 'EUR' })` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation

Comment: @JordanBurnett, I think you misunderstood, the problem is how to convert a locale string as a number in any locale to a float with US decimals and separators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run through the string one character at a time, check if the character is a number, add it to a string and insert your required field separators at your specified intervals (have a counter of 3 for commas maybe?)

Comment: Thanks, I think that I may use this solution as dealing with non Arabic numerals seems like too much effort. It is still a bit tricky because you need to know if the number is the thousand separator or the decimal but it remains very manageable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tool will help you! [accounting.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/)

I'm sure you can also figure it out yourself using [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and conditionals but you're right, it's probably not worth the effort when there are many libraries available.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try to see how the unformat function behaves with most languages !

Answer (score 0):

You could get the decimal separators for the locale, then remove the thousand separator accordingly. At this time, you have a decimal value with decimal point.

Then you can parse the value to decimal correctly.

```js
let localeString = reformat('123,45,67,89.57982');

reformat(str) {
str = str.replace(/\s/, '');

let locale = 'fr-FR';

if(getLocaleDecimalSeparator(locale) === ',')
 str = str.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/, '.');
else if(getLocaleDecimalSeparator(locale) === '.')
 str = str.replace(/,/g, '');

return parseFloat(str);
}

getLocaleDecimalSeparator(locale) {
 let n = 1.1;
 //returns `,` or `.`
 return n.toLocaleString(locale).substring(1, 2);
}
```